# Why is umlaut not recognized in a UTF-8-encoded Perl script with "use utf8"?

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding

The following script is encoded in UTF-8:

```perl
use utf8;

$fuer = pack('H*', '66c3bc72');

$fuer =~ s/ü/!!!/;

print $fuer;
```

The `ü` in the `s///` is stored in the script as `c3 bc`, as the following `xxd` hex dump shows.

```
0000000: 75 73 65 20 75 74 66 38 3b 0a 0a 24 66 75 65 72  use utf8;..$fuer
0000010: 20 3d 20 70 61 63 6b 28 27 48 2a 27 2c 20 27 36   = pack('H*', '6
0000020: 36 63 33 62 63 37 32 27 29 3b 0a 0a 24 66 75 65  6c3bc72');..$fue
0000030: 72 20 3d 7e 20 73 2f c3 bc 2f 21 21 21 2f 3b 0a  r =~ s/../!!!/;.
0000040: 0a 70 72 69 6e 74 20 24 66 75 65 72 3b 0a        .print $fuer;.
```

`c3 bc` is the UTF-8 representation for `ü`.

Since the script is encoded in UTF-8 and I am `use`ing `utf8`, I expected the script to replace the `für` in the variable `$fuer` - yet it doesn't.

It does, however, if I remove the `use utf8`. This runs against what I thought `use utf8` was for: to indicate that the script is encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with character boundaries. You are comparing an encoded string of bytes with a decoded character string

`$fuer = pack('H*', '66c3bc72')` creates the four-byte string `"\x66\xc3\xbc\x72"`, whereas a small u with diaeresis `ü` is `"\xfc"` so the two don't match

If you used `decode_utf8` from the `Encode` module to further process your variable `$fuer` then it would decode the UTF-8 to form the three-character string `"\x66\xfc\x72"`, and the substitute would then work

`use utf8` applies the equivalent to `decode_utf8` to the whole source file, so without it your `ü` appears *encoded* as `"\xc3\xbc"`, which matches the packed variable

Comment: Thanks for the answer - This is the first time, I believe (hope...), that I understand the `use utf8` thing. Also, I was not aware that Perl has a concept of character boundaries. I always thought a string is just (and only) an array of bytes. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Let's move out the `ü` out of the `s///` and into its own variable so we can inspect it.

```
use utf8;                             # Script is encoded using UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal expects UTF-8.

use strict;
use warnings;

my $uuml = "ü";
printf("%d %vX %s", length($uuml), $uuml, $uuml);   # 1 FC ü

my $fuer = pack('H*', '66c3bc72');
printf("%d %vX %s", length($fuer), $fuer, $fuer);   # 4 66.C3.BC.72 fÃ¼r

$fuer =~ s/\Q$uuml/!!!/;
printf("%d %vX %s", length($fuer), $fuer, $fuer);   # 4 66.C3.BC.72 fÃ¼r
```

As this makes obvious, you are comparing the Unicode Code Point of `ü` (`FC`) against the UTF-8 encoding of `ü` (`C3 BC`).

So yes, `use utf8;` indicates that script is encoded using UTF-8 ...but it does it so that Perl can correctly decode the script.

Decode all inputs and encode all outputs! The solution is to replace

```
my $fuer = pack('H*', '66c3bc72');
```

with

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $fuer = decode_utf8(pack('H*', '66c3bc72'));
```

or

```
my $fuer = pack('H*', '66c3bc72');
utf8::decode($fuer);
```